# How to stop jQuery function which is refreshing the page in JSF?

Tags: jquery, jsf, page-refresh

I am learning JSF and want to integrate it with jQuery. But it is not working properly as page is refreshed on its own. I have tried `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` too, but without success.

Here is jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form2\\:button1").click(function(){
        $("#form2\\:div1").toggle("slow",function(e){
            //e.preventDefault;
            //e.stopPropagation;
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

and here is xHTML part:

```
<h:form name="form1" id="form2">
    <h:outputLabel value="Enter Date"></h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText value="#{test.date }"></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton action="#{test.doWork}" value="Submit Form"></h:commandButton>
    <h:button id="button1" value="Action"></h:button>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="div1">
        <h:commandLink id="link1"  value="Edit Details"></h:commandLink>
        <h:commandLink id="link2"  value="Manage mails" > </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

I am trying to apply jQuery function on `#button1`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`<h:button>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) tag

> renders an HTML "input" element of type "button". The value of the component is rendered as the button text and the outcome of the component is used to determine the target URL which is activated by onclick ... if this result (outcome) is null, let outcome be the viewId of the current UIViewRoot

In other words, this tag generates an `input` element with JavaScript redirection (by specifying `window.location.href`) to the navigation case outcome specified in its `outcome` attribute, or, **to the current page in case `outcome` attribute is not specified**. So, now you should understand why the page is refreshed.

If you don't want the redirection to happen, just return `false` from the `onclick` method, like so:

```
<h:button id="button1" value="Action" onclick="$('#form2\\:div1').toggle('slow');return false;"/>
```

The same applies to your jQuery code.

Otherwise you could simply consider using plain HTML `<button>` tag to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

The prevention of the event should occur inside the `onclick` callback, not inside the `toggle` callback.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form2\\:button1").click(function(){ 

        $("#form2\\:div1").toggle("slow"); 

        //e.preventDefault;
        //e.stopPropagation;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PNcZS/1/.

Comment: Unfortunately you're unfamiliar with JSF, so your answer is wrong. JSF renders id of the component in question as `form2:button1` and it is not a selector for all `button` elements as you seemed to expect. Finally, no `button` element will be rendered at all, but `input` element will.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about naming containers in JSF. My bad. I will update the fiddle to reflect the changes for the jsf rendered html. My point on the event on the click still stands?